# A simple question about substituting a common part of a file name when concatenating txt files

Tags: python, concatenation

I have many many files where the starting 3 letters is different. I am trying to concatenate the monthly files into semi annually using the code below. But rather than replace FXE 7 times with the different letters, I want to just replace it in 1 place. I tried a few methods including using ETF = FXE and then substituting FXE for {ETF} but my inexperience with the syntax is stumping me. Any quick advice is appreciated. Thx in advance.

```
# Creating a list of filenames
filenames = ['FXE_2022_01.txt', 'FXE_2022_02.txt', 'FXE_2022_03.txt', 'FXE_2022_04.txt', 'FXE_2022_05.txt', 'FXE_2022_06.txt']
  
# Open file3 in write mode
with open('FXE_2022_01_to_06.txt', 'w') as outfile:
  
    # Iterate through list
    for names in filenames:
  
        # Open each file in read mode
        with open(names) as infile:
  
            # read the data from file1 and
            # file2 and write it in file3
            outfile.write(infile.read())
  
        # Add '\n' to enter data of file2
        # from next line
        outfile.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way to do it using list comprehension and f strings. I also generalized the year and index numbers:

```
f_headers = ['FXE', 'ETF', 'GBJ']
f_year = '2022'
f_range = list(range(1,7))

fnames = [[f'{fh}_{f_year}_{fr:02d}.txt' for fr in f_range] for fh in f_headers]
for fn in fnames:
    print(fn)
```

Output:

```
['FXE_2022_01.txt', 'FXE_2022_02.txt', 'FXE_2022_03.txt', 'FXE_2022_04.txt', 'FXE_2022_05.txt', 'FXE_2022_06.txt']
['ETF_2022_01.txt', 'ETF_2022_02.txt', 'ETF_2022_03.txt', 'ETF_2022_04.txt', 'ETF_2022_05.txt', 'ETF_2022_06.txt']
['GBJ_2022_01.txt', 'GBJ_2022_02.txt', 'GBJ_2022_03.txt', 'GBJ_2022_04.txt', 'GBJ_2022_05.txt', 'GBJ_2022_06.txt']
```